# How to implement search on a mysql database using Android App?

Tags: php, android, json, android-adapter, searchview

Basically, I am developing an online library management system. I have successfully displayed the whole database as a listView using PHP, JSON and Async Task. Now I need to search that listView  and and display the selected item's detail in a new Activity.

Comment: sql `where` and some appropriate parameters for your http call? if you've gotten this far, it's just a few extra steps to actually FILTER the whole database.

Comment: you can make a REST webservice in php and let the android app call that service. JSON would be returned to the app and then app can handle the displaying part. Alternatively you can also develop a Single Page Application for the same and call it in the webView for android app.  You can use WHERE, MATCH AGAINST and HAVING for searching the data in DB

Comment: Thank you @SaurabhSinha. The alternate step helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating your new activity with a WebView that opens your PHP url with a query string dictating your search. [This](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/) would be a start.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String stringPassed = intent.getExtras().getString("searchParam");

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.yoursite.com/search/?string="+stringPassed);

}
```

Your listView will have to pass strings to your webView activity in order to dynamically generate your query string, which is subsequently used to generate your search parameters.

Comment: anyone can send this project please, the link is google webview, but i need that come from webserver.